# How can I make a div height smaller than one pixel on mobile device?

Tags: html, css, mobile, height, pixel

I'm trying to create a list view, whith a light line at the bottom of each element to separate them (my website is a mobile site only).
I am noting, that 1px has a different height on my iphone pro 11 max, and my samsung a5...
I think that there is nothing smaller than 1px, but, seem to set height in em, is smaller (and prettier for me).
Can I use, 0.03em for all my height like this ? (1px is too big and ugly).
Here is my demo : `https://codepen.io/lokomass/pen/ExVKQjK`

```
<div class="page">
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="content-block">
        <div class="list-block">
            <ul>
                <li class="a">
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div>ligne</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="b">
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div>ligne</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
ul {
      list-style: none;
}
li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      position: relative;
}
li:after {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
.a:after {
    height: 1px;
}
.b:after {
    height: 0.03em;
}
```

[Here is a snap from my iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym2SH.png)

Comment: try to change color of this height with rgb, make it with grey color.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can add opacity, so it looks smaller. :)
Or change the color.
try this:

```css
ul {
      list-style: none;
}
li {
      padding: 10px 0;
      position: relative;
}
li:after {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
.a:after {
    height: 1px;
}
.b:after {
    height: 0.03em;
  opacity:0.5;
}
.c:after {
    height: 1px;
  background-color:#B2B2B2;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="content-block">
        <div class="list-block">
            <ul>
                <li class="a">
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div>ligne</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="b">
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div>ligne</div>
                    </div>
                  
                <li class="c">
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div>ligne</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when I zoom on my iphone, I can't see a difference between 1px and 0.3em, how can epxlain this ?

Comment: when you zoom in, you will obviously see the difference. however, in HTML and CSS, you cannot actually have height/width smaller than 1px, and all UI/UX applications that seem to use elements that are smaller than 1px are just using a lighter color or a fancy gradient trick to make the element look narrower.